# Targeting Specific Image Templates

Tags: theming, media

I'm trying to implement a script for lazy loading images on my site and I'm not sure how to target specific image templates. I need to change the `src` attribute to `data-src` and add a class.

All images are currently using `image.html.twig`. If I change that template it almost works but ends up changing some images it shouldn't.

What would be a good way to modify the attributes of these images based on their use within specific paragraphs across the site?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Three approaches (of many that are possible):

A good way would be to use a custom field formatter for images with data-src and configure this field formatter in the paragraph type. This is a module solution, but I think this is a good idea anyway to bundle this feature including the libraries.

A theming solution would be to add an attribute to each image field in a paragraph preprocess hook and then check for this attribute in the image template.

The easiest solution is to create a separate image style for lazy loading and check the style name in the image template.